# GSL and environment variables

Tags: c, environment-variables, gsl

After building:

```
$ gcc generator.c -lm  -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
gsl_rng * r;
/* global generator */
int main (void)
{
    const gsl_rng_type * T;
    gsl_rng_env_setup();
    T = gsl_rng_default;
    r = gsl_rng_alloc (T);
    printf ("generator type: %s\n", gsl_rng_name (r));
    printf ("seed = %lu\n", gsl_rng_default_seed);
    printf ("first value = %lu\n", gsl_rng_get (r));
    gsl_rng_free (r);
    return 0;
}
```

And then run it in the way :

```
$ ./a.out
```

I get:

```
generator type: mt19937
seed = 0
first value = 4293858116
```

If I do:

```
$ GSL_RNG_SEED=1  GSL_RNG_TYPE="taus" ./a.out
```

I get:

```
GSL_RNG_TYPE=taus
GSL_RNG_SEED=1
generator type: taus
seed = 1
first value = 802792108
```

But after doing:

```
$ GSL_RNG_SEED=1
$ GSL_RNG_TYPE="taus"
$ ./a.out
```

I get same output as the first time:

```
generator type: mt19937
seed = 0
first value = 4293858116
```

Why the executable does not get the environment variable values (GSL_RNG_SEED=1 and GSL_RNG_TYPE="taus") in last way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use export to set the environment variables. So 

`export GSL_RNG_SEED=1
export GSL_RNG_TYPE="taus"`